# How to solve this integral equation,how to solve for $\phi(x,y,z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

A continuous mapping $$\phi :R^3 \to R$$
$ r=\sqrt{|x-x'|^2+|y-y'|^2+|z-z'|^2}$

for $x,y,z,x',y',z',k \in R$

$k$ is a constant

**The integral equation :**$$\phi(x,y,z)=k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\phi(x',y',z')}{4\pi r}dx'dy'dz'$$

ofcourse trivial solution is $\phi=0$

The question is how to solve for non trivial soluions for $\phi(x,y,z)$  ?

Remark :consider the solution of **Differential equation** :$$\frac {\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\frac {\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}=-k\phi$$ which is Helmholtz equation . Given that $\phi$ is continuous and absolutely integrable in $R^3$ and If the partial derivatives of $\phi$ exist at every point and are absolutely integrable in $R^3$ , the integral equation and the differential equation are equivalent. Non trivial solutions of the differential equation  (Helmholtz equation) are known but I was unable solve the integral equation or show that the solutions of the differential equation also solves the integral equation.